# nginx: disable open_file_cache for specific file

Tags: nginx, cache

we are using nginx with file cache on:

```
http {
    open_file_cache           max=10000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid     60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses  4;
    open_file_cache_errors    off;
}
```

then we want to show 503 Maintanance error page when one file exists on FS with config:

```
server {
    root   /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        if (-f /var/www/html/storage/framework/down) {
            return 503;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is a delay after this file is deleted from FS; 503 is still returning some time (maybe minute), probably because of open_file_cache cached it.

It is possible to disable `open_file_cache` for that specific file (file is outside of server root) and leave it enabled for rest of filesystem? Or what are our options, when we need no delay after turning on webpage in framework (which only delete that one file). We are using Laravel and their `up` and `down` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's likely no way to win here through NGINX configuration alone. Even if you were able to disable open file caching for that single maintenance check file, it would probably not worth it in terms of performance. Think how this file would be constantly re-checked on every single request, over and over again... not good.

You probably will end up using `systemctl reload nginx` in order to clear up open file cache altogether, after switching the maintenance on or off. Which makes sense. Provided that maintenance was done in order to update/add/delete some files, you need to clear the entire open file cache, not just for the maintenance file.

Finally, as an alternative to putting open file cache on the entire site and using `systemctl reload nginx` after running maintenance enablement/disablement commands, you can simply locate where your static files are, and create the necessary `location`s and enabling open file cache only there (disabling on the `http` level).